# jQuery - How to exclude <p> from fadeTo

Tags: jquery

So I am designing a website with circular icons at the bottom of the home page.  The icons are pictures and when a user's mouse toggles over them I want the picture to fade out to 33% and a piece of text to appear. I have everything working except jQuery is also fading out the text that is appearing, which I do not want it to do. For example, I want to fade "circular_one" while not fading "abt." Here is my code:

```
        <div class="bottom_images">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="circular_one">
                        <p class="abt" id="abt">About</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>      
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                    <div class="circular_two">
                        <p class="adv" id="adv">Adventure</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>      
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                    <div class="circular_three">
                        <p class="int" id="int">Intellect</p>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>                  
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.circular_one .abt {
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 110px;
padding-right: 110px;
padding-left: 90px;
padding-bottom: 110px;
display: none;
font-size: 35px;

}

.circular_two .adv {
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 110px;
padding-right: 110px;
padding-left: 45px;
padding-bottom: 110px;
display: none;
font-size: 35px;

}

.circular_three .int {
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 110px;
padding-right: 110px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-bottom: 110px;
display: none;
font-size: 35px;
```

jQuery:

```
var main = function() {

$('.circular_one').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('.abt').show();

});     

$('.circular_one').mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('.abt').hide();   

});     

$('.circular_two').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('.adv').show();

}); 

$('.circular_two').mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('.adv').hide();

});     

$('.circular_three').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('.int').show();

}); 

$('.circular_three').mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('.int').hide();

});         
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765447/jquery-fade-out-when-clicking-on-parent-element-and-not-the-parents-children

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `e.target` to see what element was actually clicked:

e.g

```
$('.circular_two').mouseenter(function(e) {  //added 'e' here 
    if ($(e.target).is('.circular_two'))   // check to verify if this is the same element where we need fading
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
        $('.adv').show();
    } // end if
});
```

Do the same for the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you change opacity to an element, it will affect its children. In my example below, I've made the elements siblings to eachother instead, keeping them on the same level.

You're repeating yourself quite a lot. Create a common `circular` class and bind the events to that:

The `hover` event is a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```
$('.circular').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('div').stop(true).fadeTo(200, '0.3');
}, function(){
    $(this).find('div').stop(true).fadeTo(200, '1');
});
```

Nore that I `stop()` animations to prevent them from queueing up.

http://jsfiddle.net/bxomf6z6/1/

Comment: When I added this the fading stops working all together.

Comment: You can't just "add it". Did you change the sctructure as I said?

Comment: I changed the structure exactly like you have it and now the text doesn't fade, but when I hover over the image icon the text appears in the corner and pushed the icon down--they will no longer overlap when the span is "shown."